# Run A Macro By Clicking A Specific Cell In Excel with a condition/if statement

Tags: excel, vba

I have successfully got this code working where you click on any cell in the range `F6:F16` and a date picker pops up and enters the date selected in the active cell. However, I would like to add a condition to running the macro that makes the date picker pop up, so that it only runs if the cell to the left contains the word *"Date:"* and if the cell to the left is blank, nothing should happen.

e.g. When I click on cell `F8`, I want the macro to run (i.e. date picker to pop up) if cell `E8` contains *"Date:"*, but if cell `E8` is blank, the macro must not run (i.e. date picker must not pop up).

Hope that makes sense.
Here is my existing code without the condition:

**Sheet 1 (Code)**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F6:F18")) Is Nothing Then
            Call datePick
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Selection.Count = 1 Then
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F6:F18")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Offset(0,-1).Value = "Date:" Then
            Call datePick
        End If
    End If
End If
End Sub
```